# Android kotlin assigning a list row to variable error

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to update the view state in the view model using a row from a list object

```
val update = getCurrentViewStateOrNew()
val updatedRow = update.editLog?.distortion?.get(0)?.copy(
        allOrNothing = allOrNothing ?: null,
)
update.editLog?.distortion?.get(0) = updatedRow
setViewState(update)
```

On the second last line the IDE has underlined the `.get(0)` in red stating `"variable expected"`. I do not know what it wants from me or how to get this error to go away. I'm simply trying to update the current view state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to set a value using a `getter` method.

You need to get the list, update the first index, then set that updated list to the `ViewState`.

```kotlin
val update = getCurrentViewStateOrNew()
val updatedRow = update.editLog?.distortion?.get(0)?.copy(
        allOrNothing = allOrNothing ?: null,
)
val distortions: ArrayList<Distortion> = ArrayList()
update.editLog?.distortion?.let{ list ->
  distortions.addAll(list)
}
distortions.set(0, updatedRow)
update.editLog?.distortion = distortions
setViewState(update)
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin has special operators for collections called `get` and `set`.

- Using `get` you can only return a value.
- Using `set` you can only set a value.

It means you cannot assign a new value to the result returned by the `get` operator.

What you need to do instead is either use `set` operator which accepts two arguments: index of the element and the element itself.

```
update.editLog?.distortion?.set(0, updatedRow)
```

Alternative is to use brackets on an unwrapped array, making sure it is not null:

```
update.editLog?.distortion?.let {
    it[0] = updatedRow
}
```

[Read more](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/list-operations.html#updating) here about updating lists.

[Read more](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/list-operations.html#retrieving-elements-by-index) here about retrieving values from a list.

Comment: The .set is not available. The ide shows the word in red but you rlogic makes sense. Not sure how to get to the set method. When I highlight the red set word it says "Unresolved Reference : None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch "

Comment: @AndroidDev123, Updated the answer with alternative. What is the type of `distortion` variable? If possible give full canonical name like `java.util.List`.

Comment: The alternative has an error on the it[0] it states no set method providing array access

Comment: distortion is a List<DistortionCacheEntity> which is a Room table. Im accessing it through a model class, update the model then update the table

Comment: @AndroidDev123, this is the problem. Room returns you **an immutable** list. Immutable lists (better to say - collections) do not allow any modifications. This is the reason why you cannot set a new value.

Comment: I actually do this many times in the viewmodel. The difference in my above example is fact that this model has a List instead of just individual vars. When dealing with individual vars aka table columns The above function works perfectly. I need to find a way to make it work with the list

Comment: `List` type is immutable by itself. In order for it to be mutable in Java it could be an `ArrayList` and in Koltin `MutableList`. But Room does not return lists of these types.

Comment: Does that mean my users cannot update data in the app relating to the List<DistortionCacheEntity>

Comment: It means that you have to create [a method to update](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#convenience-update) your table view and reload data after a successful update of a table (or [use `LiveData` to observe changes](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-observable) in table view in realtime*).

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to make an assignment to the return value of the `get` method.

You probably meant to set that element of the list:

```
update.editLog?.distortion?.set(0, updatedRow)
```

You can't use the normal `[]` syntax due to it being nullable.

Comment: The .set is not available. The ide shows the word in red but you rlogic makes sense. Not sure how to get to the set method. When I highlight the red set word it says "Unresolved Reference : None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch "

Comment: Could you provide a [mre]? I have no way of debugging this without knowing the types of the variables.  (the rest of the error message you pasted might also help)

Comment: I cant mate its a huge project built on Clean arch and MVI with dozens of classes involved.

Comment: That link should give you advice on how to create a minimal example without the rest of the project (I usually use the "start from scratch" approach and build a simple example on https://play.kotlinlang.org).